# Javassist - redirect field access to methods (doesn't work)

Tags: java, javassist

I have the following Class

```
public class Booking{

    public String name;
    public String comment;

    public String session;

    public void test(){
        this.name = "hi";
    }
}
```

I instrument it using the following:

```
cc.instrument(new ExprEditor(){
    public void edit(FieldAccess arg) throws CannotCompileException {
        if (arg.isWriter()) {
            StringBuffer code = new StringBuffer();
            code.append("$0.");
            code.append(arg.getFieldName());
            code.append("=$1.toUpperCase();");
            arg.replace(code.toString());
        }
    }           
});
```

Now when I call this:

```
Booking b = new Booking();
b.name = "hello";
System.out.println(b.name); // Edited correction

b.test();
System.out.println(b.name);
```

Gives me

```
hello // Externally, doesn't.
HI    // Internally, works as expected
```

What am I missing? It just seems like one of those things I should be able to accomplish easily.

Please don't tell me I have to do a blanket "fieldAccess.replace" on all classes? O.O

Comment: Is the first print supposed to be println(b.name) instead of ""?

Answer (score 3):

Your example code fragment that contains the statement b.name = "hello"; isn't being instrumented, hence the value it writes is not converted to uppercase. An ExprEditor can only transform the field access from classes that are instrumented by it. If you want every write to the 'name' field converted to uppercase, you will have to instrument every class that contains a write statement for that field.